# Using Smarty Modifier

Tags: php, smarty, modifier

I found this Smarty modifier on smartys website that is a post to convert bbcode in to html but i can't find or it don't say what the syntax is to use it for example.

```
{$bbcode_here|bbcode2html}
```

Could someone please tell or show me how to use this Smarty modifier is below.

```
function smarty_modifier_bbcode2html($message) {
  $preg = array(
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[color(?::\w+)?=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/color(?::\w+)?\]/si'   => "<span style=\"color:\\1\">\\2</span>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[size(?::\w+)?=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/size(?::\w+)?\]/si'     => "<span style=\"font-size:\\1\">\\2</span>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[font(?::\w+)?=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/font(?::\w+)?\]/si'     => "<span style=\"font-family:\\1\">\\2</span>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[align(?::\w+)?=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/align(?::\w+)?\]/si'   => "<div style=\"text-align:\\1\">\\2</div>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[b(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/b(?::\w+)?\]/si'                 => "<span style=\"font-weight:bold\">\\1</span>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[i(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/i(?::\w+)?\]/si'                 => "<span style=\"font-style:italic\">\\1</span>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[u(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/u(?::\w+)?\]/si'                 => "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline\">\\1</span>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[center(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/center(?::\w+)?\]/si'       => "<div style=\"text-align:center\">\\1</div>",

          // [code] & [php]
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[code(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/code(?::\w+)?\]/si'           => "<div class=\"bb-code\">\\1</div>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[php(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/php(?::\w+)?\]/si'             => "<div class=\"bb-php\">\\1</div>",
          // [email]
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[email(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/email(?::\w+)?\]/si'         => "<a href=\"mailto:\\1\" class=\"bb-email\">\\1</a>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[email(?::\w+)?=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/email(?::\w+)?\]/si'   => "<a href=\"mailto:\\1\" class=\"bb-email\">\\2</a>",
          // [url]
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[url(?::\w+)?\]www\.(.*?)\[\/url(?::\w+)?\]/si'        => "<a href=\"http://www.\\1\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"bb-url\">\\1</a>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[url(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/url(?::\w+)?\]/si'             => "<a href=\"\\1\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"bb-url\">\\1</a>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[url(?::\w+)?=(.*?)?\](.*?)\[\/url(?::\w+)?\]/si'      => "<a href=\"\\1\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"bb-url\">\\2</a>",
          // [img]
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[img(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/img(?::\w+)?\]/si'             => "<img src=\"\\1\" alt=\"\\1\" class=\"bb-image\" />",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[img(?::\w+)?=(.*?)x(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/img(?::\w+)?\]/si' => "<img width=\"\\1\" height=\"\\2\" src=\"\\3\" alt=\"\\3\" class=\"bb-image\" />",
          // [quote]
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[quote(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/quote(?::\w+)?\]/si'         => "<div>Quote:<div class=\"bb-quote\">\\1</div></div>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)\[quote(?::\w+)?=(?:&quot;|"|\')?(.*?)["\']?(?:&quot;|"|\')?\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/si'   => "<div>Quote \\1:<div class=\"bb-quote\">\\2</div></div>",
          // [list]
          '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[\*(?::\w+)?\](.*?)(?=(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[\*|(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[\/?list)/si' => "\n<li class=\"bb-listitem\">\\1</li>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[\/list(:(?!u|o)\w+)?\](?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si'    => "\n</ul>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[\/list:u(:\w+)?\](?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si'         => "\n</ul>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[\/list:o(:\w+)?\](?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si'         => "\n</ol>",
          '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list(:(?!u|o)\w+)?\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si'   => "\n<ul class=\"bb-list-unordered\">",
          '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list:u(:\w+)?\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si'        => "\n<ul class=\"bb-list-unordered\">",
          '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list:o(:\w+)?\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si'        => "\n<ol class=\"bb-list-ordered\">",
          '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list(?::o)?(:\w+)?=1\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si' => "\n<ol class=\"bb-list-ordered,bb-list-ordered-d\">",
          '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list(?::o)?(:\w+)?=i\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/s'  => "\n<ol class=\"bb-list-ordered,bb-list-ordered-lr\">",
          '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list(?::o)?(:\w+)?=I\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/s'  => "\n<ol class=\"bb-list-ordered,bb-list-ordered-ur\">",
          '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list(?::o)?(:\w+)?=a\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/s'  => "\n<ol class=\"bb-list-ordered,bb-list-ordered-la\">",
          '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list(?::o)?(:\w+)?=A\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/s'  => "\n<ol class=\"bb-list-ordered,bb-list-ordered-ua\">",
          // escaped tags like \[b], \[color], \[url], ...
          '/\\\\(\[\/?\w+(?::\w+)*\])/'                                      => "\\1"

  );
  $message = preg_replace(array_keys($preg), array_values($preg), $message);
  return $message;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct use of this function would be First to place the code in a PHP file that will be loaded with the calling of the smarty template.  I am assuming that you have smarty all set up and running.

You will have to change the function parameters just a little as shown:

```
function smarty_modifier_bbcode2html($params, &$smarty) {
    $message = $params['message'];
    $preg = array(
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[color(?::\w+)?=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/color(?::\w+)?\]/si'   => "<span style=\"color:\\1\">\\2</span>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[size(?::\w+)?=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/size(?::\w+)?\]/si'     => "<span style=\"font-size:\\1\">\\2</span>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[font(?::\w+)?=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/font(?::\w+)?\]/si'     => "<span style=\"font-family:\\1\">\\2</span>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[align(?::\w+)?=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/align(?::\w+)?\]/si'   => "<div style=\"text-align:\\1\">\\2</div>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[b(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/b(?::\w+)?\]/si'                 => "<span style=\"font-weight:bold\">\\1</span>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[i(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/i(?::\w+)?\]/si'                 => "<span style=\"font-style:italic\">\\1</span>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[u(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/u(?::\w+)?\]/si'                 => "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline\">\\1</span>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[center(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/center(?::\w+)?\]/si'       => "<div style=\"text-align:center\">\\1</div>",

      // [code] & [php]
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[code(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/code(?::\w+)?\]/si'           => "<div class=\"bb-code\">\\1</div>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[php(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/php(?::\w+)?\]/si'             => "<div class=\"bb-php\">\\1</div>",
      // [email]
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[email(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/email(?::\w+)?\]/si'         => "<a href=\"mailto:\\1\" class=\"bb-email\">\\1</a>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[email(?::\w+)?=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/email(?::\w+)?\]/si'   => "<a href=\"mailto:\\1\" class=\"bb-email\">\\2</a>",
      // [url]
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[url(?::\w+)?\]www\.(.*?)\[\/url(?::\w+)?\]/si'        => "<a href=\"http://www.\\1\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"bb-url\">\\1</a>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[url(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/url(?::\w+)?\]/si'             => "<a href=\"\\1\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"bb-url\">\\1</a>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[url(?::\w+)?=(.*?)?\](.*?)\[\/url(?::\w+)?\]/si'      => "<a href=\"\\1\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"bb-url\">\\2</a>",
      // [img]
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[img(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/img(?::\w+)?\]/si'             => "<img src=\"\\1\" alt=\"\\1\" class=\"bb-image\" />",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[img(?::\w+)?=(.*?)x(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/img(?::\w+)?\]/si' => "<img width=\"\\1\" height=\"\\2\" src=\"\\3\" alt=\"\\3\" class=\"bb-image\" />",
      // [quote]
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[quote(?::\w+)?\](.*?)\[\/quote(?::\w+)?\]/si'         => "<div>Quote:<div class=\"bb-quote\">\\1</div></div>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)\[quote(?::\w+)?=(?:&quot;|"|\')?(.*?)["\']?(?:&quot;|"|\')?\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/si'   => "<div>Quote \\1:<div class=\"bb-quote\">\\2</div></div>",
      // [list]
      '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[\*(?::\w+)?\](.*?)(?=(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[\*|(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[\/?list)/si' => "\n<li class=\"bb-listitem\">\\1</li>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[\/list(:(?!u|o)\w+)?\](?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si'    => "\n</ul>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[\/list:u(:\w+)?\](?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si'         => "\n</ul>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[\/list:o(:\w+)?\](?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si'         => "\n</ol>",
      '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list(:(?!u|o)\w+)?\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si'   => "\n<ul class=\"bb-list-unordered\">",
      '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list:u(:\w+)?\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si'        => "\n<ul class=\"bb-list-unordered\">",
      '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list:o(:\w+)?\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si'        => "\n<ol class=\"bb-list-ordered\">",
      '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list(?::o)?(:\w+)?=1\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/si' => "\n<ol class=\"bb-list-ordered,bb-list-ordered-d\">",
      '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list(?::o)?(:\w+)?=i\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/s'  => "\n<ol class=\"bb-list-ordered,bb-list-ordered-lr\">",
      '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list(?::o)?(:\w+)?=I\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/s'  => "\n<ol class=\"bb-list-ordered,bb-list-ordered-ur\">",
      '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list(?::o)?(:\w+)?=a\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/s'  => "\n<ol class=\"bb-list-ordered,bb-list-ordered-la\">",
      '/(?<!\\\\)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*)?\[list(?::o)?(:\w+)?=A\]\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)?/s'  => "\n<ol class=\"bb-list-ordered,bb-list-ordered-ua\">",
      // escaped tags like \[b], \[color], \[url], ...
      '/\\\\(\[\/?\w+(?::\w+)*\])/'                                      => "\\1"

   );
   $message = preg_replace(array_keys($preg), array_values($preg), $message);
   return $message;
}
```

And You will need to register the function inside your php file, generally register the function right after the function in the php file as this:

```
$smarty->register_block('bbcode2html', 'smarty_modifier_bbcode2html');
```

Now you are ready to use this inside your smarty template as shown next:

```
<p>{bbcode2html message=$messageToConvert}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to translate bbcode into html. Look here for bbcode reference: http://www.bbcode.org/reference.php